# C Проблема с scanf

Tags: c

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
unsigned char a[21] = {0};
unsigned char b[21] = {0};

printf("Enter your new password ?");
scanf("%20[A-Z, a-z, 0-9]", a);

printf("Enter agen ?");
scanf("%20s",b);

printf("\r\n%s - %s\r\n", a, b);

printf("done.\r\n");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`scanf` читает все заданые символы хорошо, но если ввсесит к примеру zorg443#, то программа просто считывает все кроме #, а потом пропускает второй `scanf` и сама записывает символ # в масив b.

вот вивод:

```
Enter your new password ?zorg443#
Enter agen ?
zorg443 - #
done.
```

Comment: Так вы же сами ограничили набор символов буквами и цифрами. Если нужен символ `#` или ещё какой, то добавьте его в шаблон: `scanf("%20[A-Z,a-z,0-9,#]", a);`

Comment: Я хотел сделать защиту от не нужных символов

Comment: Для того, что вы задумали, `scanf` не очень подходит. Если серьезно подходить к вопросу, то в подобных случаях надо читать всю строку и самому ее анализировать.

Comment: @Biggy Тогда считывайте строку целиком и посимвольно анализируйте её и как только встретите недопустимый символ, сообщайте об ошибке.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Посмотрите на такую замечательную функцию как `strspn()`.